# Save the client area after a dodle-like function as image

Tags: c++, opencv, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I have an application wherein a user can draw shapes just like on paint. I would want to save that workspace that the user created and save it as a .png image. I am using Wxwidgets in codeblocks. I used opencv for my image processing functions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the outline of how to do this:

Instead of drawing to the display DC, draw into a a wxMemoryDC

When you are ready to display your image, blit the memory DC to the display DC

When you are ready to save your image to file, select the bitemap out of the memory DC

Save the bitmap to file

```
wxMemoryDC memDC;
wxBitmap bitmap(200, 200);
memDC.SelectObject(bitmap);
memDC.SetBackground(*wxWHITE_BRUSH);
memDC.Clear();
memDC.SetPen(*wxRED_PEN);
memDC.SetBrush(*wxTRANSPARENT_BRUSH);
memDC.DrawRectangle(wxRect(10, 10, 100, 100));
memDC.SelectObject(wxNullBitmap);
bitmap.SaveFile("fname.png",wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
```